# Distance $d(M,\mathcal{D})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry

For $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, we define $\operatorname d(x,A)=\operatorname{inf}_{a\in A}||x-a||$, how to find $\operatorname d((M,\mathcal{D})$, where $M=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and 
$\mathcal{D}$ is the line of unit vector $(a, b, c)$. We can consider that the $\mathcal{D}$ passes through the origin. Thanks.

Comment: Find the line passing through $M$ and perpendicular to $\mathcal D$. If the intersection is $H$, then $d(M,\mathcal D)=MH$.

Comment: Thanks  @Aretino 2 for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,a\in \mathbb R^3$ and $\mathcal D$ is the line $\{ta:\ t\in\mathbb R\}$, then you want to minimize the expression
$$\tag{1}
\|x-ta\|^2=\|x\|^2+t^2\|a\|^2-2t\,x\cdot a
$$
(using that $\|y\|^2=y\cdot y$). We work with the square because it is simpler, and the square of the distance will be smallest precisely when the distance is smallest.

The formula in $(1)$ represents a convex parabola, so its minimum will be found where the derivative is zero. That is, for $t$ such that 
$$
0=2t\|a\|^2-2\,x\cdot a.
$$
That is, $t=x\cdot a /\|a\|^2$. Replacing in $(1)$ and taking the square root, we get
$$
\text{dist}(M,\mathcal D)=\sqrt{\|x\|^2-\frac{(x\cdot a)^2}{\|a\|^2}}.
$$
Using that $x\cdot a=\|x\|\,\|a\|\,\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $a$, we can get
$$
\text{dist}(M,\mathcal D)=\|x\|\,\sin\theta.
$$
If you want to write the points as $(x,y,z)$ and $(a,b,c)$, then the distance is given by 
\begin{align}
\text{dist}(M,\mathcal D)&=\sqrt{\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2)}{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\\ \ \\
&=\sqrt{\frac{x^2(b^2+c^2)+y^2(a^2+c^2)+z^2(a^2+b^2)}{a^2+b^2+c^2}}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks @Martin Argerami, it's clear now. But i have no ideas why the expression $a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2$ in final expression, i think that an algebraic expression of $x.\tilde{a}=(ax+by+cz)$. Thanks again.

Comment: It's $(x\cdot a)^2$, i.e. $[(x,y,z)\cdot(a,b,c)]^2$.

Comment: Ok @Martin Argerami